# Can a client request the task to the same worker

Tags: c, gearman

I'm using the gearman C library, what I want to do is the following:

first, client add a task, and the server assign to some worker.

next, the client add another task, I want the same worker to do the task.

Is it any way to achieve this??

Comment: So same client <-> same worker? Are you sure this is for the best in your case? Because this potentially slows things down for the client. It's fine of course if there is a sound reason to do it this way.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Which os the parts is causing you trouble? Add a task by the client, assign a worker at the server? What have you tried? Maybe you can post the relevant parts of the code.

Comment: Thanks for replying guys. At first the client add a task like asking the working to execute some really long algorithm, and then at some point the same client wants to tell the worker that he wants it to drop the job, how to achieve this?